# Sublime Text won't install EasyClangComplete

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

On attempting to use package control to install EasyClangComplete in sublime text 3 on gentoo, I got the following error:

```
Package Control: The dependency 'pygments' is not currently installed; installing...
Package Control: The dependency 'pygments' is not available
Package Control: The dependency 'pygments' could not be installed or updated
```

I have pygments installed (dev-python/pygments), and I have also tried installing it using pip (No difference).

In the console, I got this for the sys.path

`['/opt/sublime-text3', '/opt/sublime-text3/python3.3.zip', '/home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Lib/python3.3', '/home/username/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages']`

Whereas the pygments module has installed under `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages`.

I don't have python 3.3 installed on this machine, so I guess that sublime comes with it. I tried pasting the 3.9 package into the sys.path locations regardless, no difference.

I have looked online for other people with this error, only to find people from 2018 who had problems with sublime text dealing with TLS. This is not the same thing. I also think it's probably not an issue with package control or easyclangcomplete, or else I would have been able to find this issue with the keywords I've searched.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, it seems to work now.

I've done a full system update(Upgraded packages including python 3.8 and 3.9, although I updated sublime text before that to no effect), and restarted everything(Which I had tried before withhout effect), but other than that I can't see why it can find and install pygments now whereas it couldn't before.